# Should I close a question now I have moved jobs and can no longer verify answers?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, old-questions

I posted [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4193390/forms-authentication-across-applications/10349166) (my first ever!) in November 2010 but I have since moved to a new job.

Someone has just posted a new answer.  I have no way of knowing whether or not the suggested answer will solve the problem as I do not have the original code.

What is the best course of action here?  Should I close my question entirely?

It seems unfair to let people post answers if I can never verify whether they are correct.  Maybe the question is too localised anyway.

Comment: Agree with your last sentence - it is rather localized IMO.

Comment: I'm all for burning it on the stack.

Comment: Thanks all, looks like the community has done its thing and closed it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a year and 5 months that question has only garnered:

1. Two answers -- one deleted, and one not much more than a guessing comment.
2. One comment. also a guess.
3. Only 263 views.
4. No favorites.

Since you cannot verify an answer, and no one seems to have a "me too" issue, I recommend:

1. <strike>Edit your question to add something like:</strike>

   > <strike>Update: I no longer have any way to test answers to this question, sorry.</strike>

   **Update:**  [This was done.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4193390/331508)
2. <strike>Close the question.</strike> ***Update:*** The question was closed by the community.

The question will still be around, in case someone does eventually find it helpful -- It will be closed, not deleted.
But, it will signal to people that they might better attempt to answer other questions, or that their related question is less-likely to be a duplicate.

Comment: I disagree. A closed question is on most cases, if found, not helpful. This is like abandoned Forum-Threads which you stumble upon while researching problems, they just take time away.

Comment: What's more unhelpful, @Kobobby... stumbling upon a localized question where no one has the means to replicate the failure or test solutions?  Or seeing that the post is closed, and not even clicking the link?  Closing this question means that people searching for answers are LESS likely to waste their time, unless the question otherwise looks like a solid match.

Comment: I'm all for deleting it...if that answers it...