# What to do if you have a question without a (sufficient) answer, but you can't validate/test new answers?

Tags: discussion, questions

I have two current questions for which I haven't gotten a sufficient answer yet. Both are related to an internship project and both have to do with performance. Within a week I will be moving away, and although I can try to recreate the problems back home I don't know if I can (or if I will have time for it). Since it's performance related I have to test it before I can accept an answer, or I won't know if it actually improves the performance. This means that, if someone answers after next week, I won't be able to accept the answer. What should I do with the questions?

The questions I refered to where: [Why is the same SQLite query being 30 times slower when fetching only twice as many results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10531898/why-is-the-same-sqlite-query-being-30-times-slower-when-fetching-only-twice-as-m) and [Is uninterruptible sleep the cause of my Python program being really slow (and if so, how can I solve this?)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10854817/is-uninterruptible-sleep-the-cause-of-my-python-program-being-really-slow-and-i). But I was also wondering if there was an etiquette for it, regardless of the question.

Comment: If they're not very applicable outside of your projects, you could try to close them as "Too localized".

Comment: Could you link to the questions? A [similar question has been asked before](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130519/should-i-close-a-question-now-i-have-moved-jobs-and-can-no-longer-verify-answers) and the particular questions were deemed too localized.

Answer (score 2):

You should only accept an answer if you consider your question to be "resolved". Accepting an answer without knowing for sure if it solved the problem or not could lead others to incorrect solutions down the line.

Leaving a question unaccepted isn't against the rules. It just means that you never were able to pinpoint the cause of the problem... and it sounds like this is the case.

Answer (score 1):

Either answer the question yourself by describing how your problem was eventually resolved at your old workplace before you left, even if less than satisfactorily, and accept your answer; or state the status of the question prominently within its body.

You can also accept an existing answer that has significantly, even if incompletely, helped you to make progress or to understand the problem; you can add a comment to the answer to qualify why you accept it.