# I have left a problem in the past, unable to validate incoming answers. Should I leave it without an accepted answer?

Tags: discussion

I asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9034145/how-do-i-use-cvremap-with-forward-mesh-not-reverse-mesh-to-warp-images) about a problem I was having at work. It was soon solved by a colleague of mine, but in a closed source manner. I was able to provide to the community only a hint of how this was done and I am quite sure this is not helpful to anyone.

I have moved on, leaving the problem behind. I am unlikely to encounter the exact same problem, and am unable to validate any proposed solution in order to accept an answer (at most I can say "well, what you propose seems to work").

What do I do now? Should I leave the question behind, without an accepted answer?

Comment: If you're worried about the others losing rep if you delete the question, don't; their rep won't be affected because their answers have been up for >= 6 months :)

Comment: I think the answers are partially helpful and better than nothing.

Comment: Related - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136466/what-to-do-if-you-have-a-question-without-a-sufficient-answer-but-you-cant-v?rq=1