# How should I treat an old, active question I no longer need answered?

Tags: discussion, questions, old-questions

Possible duplicate of: [Should I close a question now I have moved jobs and can no longer verify answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130519/should-i-close-a-question-now-i-have-moved-jobs-and-can-no-longer-verify-answers)

The question: [IllegalStateException - @ComponentScanning a springframework package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27664335/illegalstateexception-componentscanning-a-springframework-package/27669327?noredirect=1#comment90020159_27669327)

I asked a question nearly 4 years ago after encountering a problem doing a Java tutorial. After a few days I think I gave up and moved on to something else.

However, the question periodically receives new upvotes, answers and seems to have a good number of views. In total:

- 6 upvotes
- 1 Favorite
- 16K views
- 3 answers

I've tried to post comments to the ticket to make it clear I never found resolution and moved on, but I'm not sure if I should do something else. A few options that seem available:

1. **Delete or close the question** - likely not preferable since it seems people are still having this issue.
2. **Leave the question open** - Seems preferable given the lack of resolution
3. **Accept my own answer saying I never found a fix**.

Note: the possible duplicate I listed above was apparently rather localized; I can't gauge if that would apply in this case given the question is no longer viewable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [possible duplicate you identified](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130519/should-i-close-a-question-now-i-have-moved-jobs-and-can-no-longer-verify-answers) is about a case where the question didn't have much engagement or value, and the answer there was to either edit or close it.  That characterization doesn't seem to apply to your current question; 16k views and several answers means it's probably helping people, or at least signals that there are lots of people interested in getting an answer to that question.

While we ask questions because *we* have problems we need help with, once posted they become community property.  If nobody else seems to care about your old question either, then sure go ahead and shut it down if you can and want to -- but if other people *do* care, it's not really right to try to shut it down if it's otherwise a good question.  Yes, you won't be accepting an answer or testing answers, but other people still benefit.

An answer saying "I didn't solve this" would be more of a non-answer, and probably would not be well-received.  You could leave a comment on the question saying you've moved on if you like, or you could just let it be.  It doesn't sound like it's hurting anything.

Answer (score 0):

If there is another reason to close the question that you are asking about, then I think that should be done now, if not long ago.

Self-deleting will not be an option if there are any upvoted answers on it.

Leaving the question open will be the default unless it is closed or deleted.

If you are unable to edit your question into a more answerable state, I think that you should bolster your own answer with a summary of the progress you have been able to make on it, given the answers so far, and then accept your own answer.

That will not prevent other answers being added and continuing to be voted upon.